# Modification on what appears to be a 'Category View' page

Tags: views

I am a Joomla developer by default but have been asked to make some minor changes to an old Drupal site to tidy up what I can only describe as a category page.

The page can be found [here](http://www.hutchesonsofportsoy.co.uk/sale-items)

I need to try and add a line/border underneath each category and align the images so that they have the same layout/vertical alignment as each other.

Can anyone advise the best way to do this? The site is not being updated due to it being migrated to Joomla in the future, thus a quick fix is all that is required at the moment.

Any suggestions would be most welcome. I'm still having a look around the site trying to figure this out, but any pointers would be most welcome.

Update: I have some custom css which may well do the job

```
    .node-sale-item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I'm now looking at how to implement it. If there are any better suggestions however i'd be happy to hear them.

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your css code for the classes `.node-promoted` and `.node-sale-item` on your [page](http://www.hutchesonsofportsoy.co.uk/sale-items), using web-inspect. It works, all you need to do is to apply the CSS to any of the classes in your theme's .css

Navigate to http://hutchesonsofportsoy.co.uk/admin/appearance (as an admin) to find out your enabled theme (usually on the top) and then copy the styles to-

**root \ sites \ all \ themes \ [enabled-theme] \ css \ [file.css]**

Comment: Thank you - I'm just waiting to see if I can get FTP access to the site and will follow your suggestion and obviously credit your answer once complete. Thank you for your guidance. :)

Comment: Sure, no problem and oh do not forget to clear the caches (admin/config/development/performance) after you copy.